# Regular expression to match $price

Tags: python, regex

I am in need of a regular expression which matches price like:
$200, $143.

So the requirements are, there should be spaces before and after the price like: ... $130 ...

and there should be a dollar sign "$" before the digits.

Help please.

P.S. I am using Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
\s\$(\d+)\s
```

**EDIT**:

As Avinash Raj noted in his answer, including the spaces in the pattern will prevent the match of sequences of prices. A better way is the one he shows with lookarounds:

```
(?<=\s\$)(\d+)(?=\s)
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dE9dH1/2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question: a dollar sign can come either before or after the digites like: $343 or 343$. How to allow this?

Comment: You could use `(?<=\s)\$(\d+)|(\d+)\$(?=\s)`

Comment: Dude I am sorry, but I have more problems: I need spaces to be optional and sometimes instead of dollar sign I may have a string "dollar". Please help

Comment: You should learn regexs yourself :) `(?:dollar[s]?|\$)\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*(?:dollar[s]?|\$)` [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dE9dH1/3)

Answer (score 2):

Use [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo $340 $350 bar'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\$\d+(?=\s)', s)
['$340', '$350']
```